# How to identify more than one label for an entity using Stanford NER

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to identify a word or entity with two labels.

For example: `John works in India.`

Output should be:

> John PER NNP
>   works O O
>   in O O
>   India LOC NNP

So it should identify the **named entity** as well as the **POS tags**.

I have created my own set of training data.

I am using the below property file

> trainFile = training.tsv
>   serializeTo = model.ser.gz
>   map = word=0,answer=1,tag=2
>   useClassFeature=true 
>   useWord=true
>   useNGrams=true
>   noMidNGrams=true
>   maxNGramLeng=6
>   usePrev=true
>   useNext=true
>   useSequences=true
>   usePrevSequences=true
>   useTags = true
>   useWordTag = true
>   useGenericFeatures = true
>   mergeTags = true
>   maxLeft=1
>   useTypeSeqs=true
>   useTypeSeqs2=true
>   useTypeySequences=true
>   wordShape=chris2useLC
>   useDisjunctive=true

The training file looks like this:

> John PER NNP
>   works O O
>   in O O
>   India LOC NNP

I am using the below code to run NER in python:

```
tagging_NER = StanfordNERTagger('.../model.ser.gz','.../stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')
token = StanfordTokenizer('.../stanford-ner.jar')
tok = token.tokenize(text)
tags = tagging_NER.tag(tok)
```

Now this code gives me just the `named entities`. It does not return me the `POS tags`.

Is there any method by which I could get both these things?

Comment: Well, the NER tagger tags named entities, that's why it's called Named Entity (Recognition) tagger. For tagging POS, you need a POS tagger. There might be tools that do both (in sequence or even simultaneously), but apparently the tool you are using simply ignores the third column.

Comment: So is there any way I could probably use that third column?

Comment: Maybe you have to write a wrapper that reformats the data to what your POS tagger expects.